# Unpacking UTF-8 Encoded Line By Position

Tags: python, utf-8

**Comment**: While I understand some concerns about the 'accuracy' of the data, I think it is really immaterial to the question. The data is what it is. Assuming so, would be interested in a possible solution.

**---------**

I need to read a file containing lines that have unicode characters. The lines contain multiple columns, each that starts at a fixed position.

Here is an example (I have put the hyphens to indicate where an individual column ends, the hyphens are actually not part of the string).
`0004-1235957-A CORU¥A       -ABC`
In the example above column 1 occupies the first 4 positions, column 2 occupies the next 7 positions, column 3 occupies the next 15 positions and column 4 occupies the next 3 positions and so on.

I am using the following code to parse this line:

```
line = '00041235957A CORU¥A       ABC\n'

formats = ('4s 7s 15s 3s')
st = struct.Struct(formats)
fields = tuple(s.decode() for s in st.unpack_from(line.encode()))
print(fields)
```

And this is the output I get:

```
('0004', '1235957', 'A CORU¥A      ', ' AB')
```

If you look at the last column, it is actually getting read incorrectly. The reason is that in unicode, the character '¥' takes up two bytes which leads to only the first 14 characters (and 15 bytes) getting read and column 4 being read from the following position.

What I want is a way to read 15 **characters** for column 3 and not 15 **bytes** independent of the encoding present in the data. Even I try substring methods on the line, I get the same behavior.

Could the experts provide some guidance on this please? Thank you.

Comment: The example looks like the input should be `A CORUÑA` (it's a city in Spain), with a letter N with tilde, not a Yen currency symbol. So there may be a decoding step going wrong. Chances are that you are dealing with an 8-bit encoding, where each character actually is 1 byte. How are you opening the file?

Comment: Files don’t contain Unicode characters.  They contain bytes representing encoded Unicode characters. The encoding is important, what may look like a single Unicode character may occupy more than one byte depending on the encoding. If you just want to split your existing Unicode string, just use string slicing instead encoding to bytes, or encode it with a single-byte encoding if you want to use the struct module, but be aware garbage-in garbage out.

Comment: @lenz it's a simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case as `'Ñ'.encode( 'cp850').decode( 'cp1252') == '¥'` returns `True`…

Answer (score 2):

When you `line.encode()` the default encoding is `utf-8`.  As you can see below, the `¥` symbol becomes two bytes `\xc2\xa5` throwing off your count:

```
>>> line = '00041235957A CORU¥A       ABC\n'
>>> line.encode()
b'00041235957A CORU\xc2\xa5A       ABC\n'
```

As the comments mentioned, you are likely mis-reading the file in the first place as a yen symbol isn't likely in the middle of what looks like a Spanish word.  Be sure you know what the original encoding of the file is so you read the file correctly.  Consider reading the file in binary e.g. `open(filename,'rb')` and posting the raw bytes of the line in question as a sample.

Below are two "solutions":

```
import struct

line = '00041235957A CORU¥A       ABC\n'

st = struct.Struct('4s7s15s3s')
# encode with a single-byte encoding so the length doesn't change.
fields = tuple(s.decode('latin1') for s in struct.unpack_from(line.encode('latin1')))
print(fields)

# slice the string directly (RECOMMENDED)
fields = line[:4],line[4:11],line[11:26],line[26:29]
print(fields)
```

Output:

```
('0004', '1235957', 'A CORU¥A       ', 'ABC')
('0004', '1235957', 'A CORU¥A       ', 'ABC')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is you want to divide the line character-wise in a readable, repeatable way you can use [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) objects.

```
>>> s1 = slice(0, 4)
>>> s2 = slice(4, 11)
>>> s3 = slice(11, 26)
>>> s4 = slice(26, 29)
>>> slices = line[s1], line[s2], line[s3], line[s4]
>>> slices
('0004', '1235957', 'A CORU¥A       ', 'ABC')
```

Slice objects are functionally the same as taking a slice from a string or list, for example `s1 = line[0:4]`, but they are independent of the sequence being sliced.

---

As pointed out in the comments and the other answer, it looks as if the data may not have be decoded correctly.  It may help to know that the byte `b'\xa5'` is mapped to "¥" in the encodings cp1252, cp1253, cp1254, cp1255, cp1256, cp1258, iso8859_15, iso8859_8, iso8859_9, latin_1, palmos, but is mapped to "Ñ‎" in the encodings cp437, cp850, cp857, cp858, cp860, cp862, cp865 ([source](https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#a5)).

Answer (score 0):

Default encoding for [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) and [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) is `utf-8` (which is a variable-width character encoding). Use a fixed-length encoding instead. Apply [`utf-32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) to correctly handle characters beyond [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

```
import struct

line = '00041235957A CORU¥A       ABC\n'

formats = ('4s 7s 15s 3s')
formats32 = '<' + ''.join([str(4*int(x))+'s' for x in formats.split('s')[:-1]])
st = struct.Struct(formats32)
fields = tuple(s.decode('utf_32_le') for s in st.unpack_from(line.encode('utf_32_le')))
print(fields)
```

**Result**: .\SO\69621626.py

```
('0004', '1235957', 'A CORU¥A       ', 'ABC')
```